# Entry procedure to Korea (long term stay?)

Tags: covid-19, south-korea, quarantine

I am looking for the current entry restrictions to Korea for a 4 months stay on a D-2 visa, entering from Japan. I have found the following [website](https://overseas.mofa.go.kr/sg-en/brd/m_2444/view.do?seq=761451), but I am not sure if I am really considered long term resident (4 months) and whether I can just self-quarantine at a hotel. I also have a Japanese vaccine passport, if that is of any help.

To be explicit: Will I be considered long term resident and can I self-quarantine at a hotel of my choice? And if yes, how can I travel to the hotel?